# Query with ODP.NET using LDAP not returning value on other computers

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g, ldap, odp.net, tns

I have written a windows application that connects to our Oracle DB and does a simple query. The query works on my development PC. when I publish the application and run it from other computers in the domain, it connects to the DB successfully but reader doesn't return any rows. it comes up with error "invalid operation against closed object" but on my development PC it returns many rows from the SELECT statement which is correct.

I have the right settings for ldap_admin and tns_admin and connection works on all the computers.

```
    Dim constr As String = "Data Source=ABC;User Id=XX;Password=XX;"
    Dim conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(constr)
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    Dim dr As OracleDataReader
    Try
        conn.Open()

        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TableA.name FROM TableA "
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        MsgBox(conn.DatabaseName)
        MsgBox(conn.HostName)
        MsgBox(conn.GetSessionInfo.TimeZone)
        MsgBox(conn.InstanceName)
        MsgBox(conn.ServiceName)
        MsgBox(conn.ConnectionTimeout)

        MsgBox(dr.HasRows() & ":" & dr.FieldCount & ":" & dr.GetName(0) & ":" & dr.IsClosed())
        dr.Read()
        MsgBox(dr.Item(0))
        If dr.Read() Then
            MsgBox("Read complete!!!")
            TextBox1.Text = dr.Item(0) ' or use dr.Item(0)
        Else

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception ' catches any error
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    Finally
        ' In a real application, put cleanup code here.


        MsgBox("Connected Successfully")
        dr.Close()

        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

I have put the msgboxes to check the connection on the other computers. The message boxes show the right info on all computers. dr.Hasrows() return only True on my development computer. All the other computers on the domain return false for that.

Can anybody help me figure this out, it is making me crazy!

Thank you,
- Hamid

Comment: Forgot to mention, it is Managed ODP.NET

Comment: Is it the query, or is the connection object bad? Try doing SELECT 'TEST' FROM DUAL

Comment: If you are getting no exception in the failure case, ask your DBA to look in the ALERT LOG on the database server for the timestamp when you tried to connect. There might be a network failure that is killing the connection and  that is only logged on the database server.

Comment: It doesn't seem it is the query as the query return the correct information in PLSQL Developer and VB.NET application on my development PC. 

I just tested something else. I removed OracleDataReader and used OracleDataAdapter instead. the same problem on the other computers in my domain 0 rows are returned. but on both computers the correct number of columns are returned when I used "Select * from" command which shows the second computer is fetching the right structure of the table but it has problem fetching the data

Comment: @ChristianShay The query "SELECT 'Test' FROM DUAL" works on every computer I tested. Returns one row with Test string!

Comment: I also queried the permissions by "select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME='XX'". It returns CREATE SESSION and SELECT ANY TABLE on every computer

Comment: What did the DBA find in the ALERT LOG?

Comment: Ok, it didn't get to that point. I spent quite a few hours since I am just a beginner in this field and I am just making a side application for one of the departments to improve their work.

Basically your first comment @ChristianShay helped a lot the SELECT 'Test' FROM DUAL. Since that worked, I looked closely at other tables and views. I noticed some return correct rows on both computers and some do not return anything. I dug more into it and found out that it was the NLS_LANGUAGE that was causing that, the computers without client installed had Canadian as for NLS but Database was US.

Comment: So basically I used OracleGlobalization class to set the session parameters and it works like a charm.

Thank you for your help!!! I will post the answer separately in case anyone comes to this post in future